# Behaviour of "trap" not as expected - after "trap" strange terminal input and no echo

Tags: bash, shell

Simple shell script 'test.sh':

```
function _trap
{
    exit 1;
}
trap "_trap" SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM;

# do something
```

If I call this script within a SSH session and type Ctrl+C the script terminates but after that the terminal does not accept regular keyboard input. There's no echo anymore and if I type RETURN there is no line break but the prompt is written within one line:

```
[foo@bar ~]$ [foo@bar ~]$ [foo@bar ~]$ [foo@bar ~]$ [foo@bar ~]$ [foo@bar ~]$ ...
```

GNU bash, Version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't really due to `trap`, your script does something else that caused it.  Try saying `stty sane`.

Comment: Execution of `stty sane` fixed that. Thanks.

Comment: @devnull consider adding your comment as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem mentioned by you isn't really due to trap, your script does something else that caused it. Saying

```
stty sane
```

should fix it.